# Change user_nicename after registration

Tags: wordpress

Say we have a a mother site. Then we have a user registration form on a 3rd party site and a user register system which is processing the whole registration process and in the end will send the user login details in the mother site's database (mysql insertion, again no user_register function). Since there are 2 completely different browser sessions, no actions can be hooked on the mother site during or after registration.

So, let's say we will have stored the users in the database with logins like `aaa@bbb.cc` (weird, yes) and having a name and the user_nicename appearing like `aaa@bbb.cc`

**Question:**

What is the best aproach, wp action/function to be hooked, that once the user is stored in the mother site's database, to write a function to change the user nicename in something like `aaa-bbb` Automatically of course.

Is there a function/hook suggested for such cases?

The below code didn't helped me, since as I told above, I think the user_register action can't be triggered when a 3rd party site registration is processed:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save' );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    $info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $args = array(
        'ID'            => $user_id,
        'user_nicename' => $info->first_name . '-' . $info->last_name
    );
    wp_update_user( $args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question as worded is really hard to understand. If I'm reading it correctly, you have two websites. Site One is where people are registering. When they complete registration on Site One something runs that creates a new user in the Site Two database by doing a direct sql insert, not by using any native WP functions.

If that's the case, why don't you simply manipulate the user login before you insert it into the Site Two db? You can't do it via a WordPress hook b/c WordPress is never being called. Hooks are just callback functions sprinkled through the WordPress code. When something happens, like a new user is created, there is a hook that you can assign a function to -- something "Send me an email." If WordPress doesn't handle the new user creation then the hook never gets called.

If you have to do the manipulation after the data has been inserted you'll probably need to look at using a cron job that runs every X amount of time looking for new records in the wp_users table.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I don't have access to the code of site One. Is there any other solution instead of cron job, to change user_nicename on site Two after user is already inserted into the db?

Comment: You need something to trigger the change. Either something has to run on one of the two sites after the user is inserted or you have to check for changes manually via cron job. Think of it this way: If I put a letter in your mail box how do you know it's there? Either I've got to tell you I put it there or you've got to open the mailbox and look. Same thing here. Something has to happen to say "Hey, new user added" so that you can then run your code.

Comment: Yes, logical, but how do I code if only a simple mysql insert was there? How can I detect that?

Comment: In the code that is doing the insert. For example, when the insert is done you could have something like if(mysql_insert_id(){  /** do something here to change the user name */ };

Now that I think about it you could probably do it with a MySQL after insert trigger (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html). For an example of how to set one up: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/